# Firestore Database: Updating missing documents

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm already testing the new `Firestore` API, and I'm having some problems regarding to the documentation and the `update` call.

I'm trying to update a no existing document and I'm recieving an error. Obviously this is fine, because the documentation say that the `update` call will fail if the `DocumentReference` doesn't exist. However, reading the [official documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/update-data) I see the next block of code:

```
// Update the population, creating the document if it
// does not already exist.
db.collection("cities").document("Beijing").update(
        new UpdateOptions().createIfMissing(),
        "population",
        21500000);
```

I'm trying to replicate this, but I don't find the `UpdateOptions` call. Also, checking the different overrides methods of `update`these is no constructor for such call.

I'm using the `11.4.2` version of Firebase. Any idea of what is happening?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Firestore API changed just before the beta launch and UpdateOptions no longer exists. If you'd like to merge fields into a document that may or may not exist use `set`, like so:

```
Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<>();
data.put("population", 21500000);

db.collection("cities").document("Beijing")
    .set(data, SetOptions.merge());
```

Unfortunately, our translated documentation is currently out of date, please refer to the English version for now.